# How to retry some methods several seconds, and when timeout throw the method's exception rather than TimeoutException in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to make a select element to select an option. But the option may not exist when the page loaded. Because the options is loading from the database, API, or something that has response time.

Currently, I use selenium wait.until with boolean condition. To make a custom wait method.

My workaround:

```java
                                                     .
                                                     .
                                                     .
String exceptionMessage;

public void myCode() throws Exception {
        exceptionMessage = "";
        Integer sec = 10;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(shared.getBrowser(), Duration.ofSeconds(sec));
        try {
            wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                    try {
                                                     .
                                                     .
                                                     .

                        CommonMethods.selectOption(element, optionText);
                        return true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            throw new Exception("Timeout: [" + sec + "] seconds, Exception message: [" + exceptionMessage + "]");
        }
}
```

If timeout the result will be:

```
java.lang.Exception: Timeout: [10] seconds, Exception message: [element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

Is there any selenium method for it? Or a better way?

Comment: Probably you can check: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: @DurgaPrasadBehera Thanks for the info. I think my custom wait is nearly to it's Custom Wait Conditions example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need as much as you've got in there.

My c# is better than my java, but this is the sort of structure i would use.
I've run it in intellij and it seems to work - but i don't have your actions and site to test it.

```
@Test
    public void myCode() throws Exception {
        exceptionMessage = "";
        Integer sec = 10;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);
        try {
            wait.until((WebDriver dr) ->
            {
                    try {
                        //Your actions go here
                        //this one will always fail - comment it out to make it pass
                        dr.findElement(By.tagName("I will fail you!")).click();
                        return true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
                        return false;
                    }

            });
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            throw new Exception("Timeout: [" + sec + "] seconds, Exception message: [" + exceptionMessage + "]");
        }
        System.out.println("The exception message is.... " + exceptionMessage);
    }
```

I've just thrown in an obvious failing element.

With this uncommented:

```
 dr.findElement(By.tagName("I will fail you!")).click();
```

It returns your timeout error catch line. I get:

> java.lang.Exception: Timeout: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ93E.png) seconds, Exception message: [no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"I\ will\ fail\ you!"}   (Session info:
> chrome=84.0.4147.105)

With it commented out - it returns nothing in the exception message (therefore returned true, therefore returned pass):

[image: intellij no error text]

Comment: Replace the boolean condition part with lambda? Great, I have test and it's working. But I still wonder to know. Is there any way to make my code less? Because there is a lot of method need to be waiting. The code lines is twice more when I add these code, and it's hard to maintain.But Anyway thanks :).

Comment: Entirely depends on how your structuring your solution and how many actions you're looking to do within the wait. I would wrap the entire wait in its own method andthe push the detail away in a relevant page object class to make it a helper method  - or split the wait process into different pieces to separate out the reusable components (the wait and the function).

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(" xpath']")));
```

Use unique Xpath to find the elements as there will some hidden elements.

If the above wait doesn't work, you can try the below as well:

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible("Yyour element path");
```

Comment: My options is dynamic loading. So element will be exist, but options might not ready.